# Set parent element of a group of nodes (wrap whole group)

Tags: html, jsoup, element

Can Jsoup set parent element of a group of nodes? I mean wrap it, but no every matched element - only create one parent element? So I want to include more elements into one?

Example: before

```
<b>some text<i> blabla </i> other text </b>
```

After

```
<span id='something'><b>some text<i> blabla </i> other text </b></span>
```

---

```
<b>some te
<span id="cke_bm_69S" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
xt</b> 
aaa 
<i>bb
<span id="cke_bm_69S" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
b</i>
```

The span tags are bookmarks - start selection and end selection - added from CKEDITOR. Then on the server side I have to process it. This is the goal - add final span and remove the temp-spans (bookmarks):

```
 <b>some te</b>
    <span id="something"><b>
    xt</b> 
    aaa 
    <i>bb
    </i></span><i>
    b</i>
```

As you can see, it has to solve the tag-crossing problem.

Comment: `<b>` is a single node here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

    Document document = Jsoup.parse("<div>"
            + "<b>some text<i> blabla </i> other text </b>" + "</div>");

    Element b = document.select("b").first();

    Element span = document.createElement("span");
    span.attr("id", "something");

    b.replaceWith(span);
    span.appendChild(b);

    System.out.println(document);
}
```

Output

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <span id="something"><b>some text<i> blabla </i> other text </b></span>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```